# Is there a way to have visibility of certain part of Nios II system memory for debug purpose?

Tags: eclipse, nios-ii

To know what value exists at address X one may simply read it using IORD and then send it via JTAG UART to the PC. However, to simplify debug process, is there a way to have visibility of certain addresses at all times where registers of certain peripheral are mapped so debugging is easier?

Answer (score 1):

It isn't entirely clear what kind of visibility you're looking for. For peripheral registers (or any other hardware nodes, for that matter), there's always SignalTap, the FPGA equivalent of a logic analyzer.

If you want to monitor the values of a few memory locations, you can add "shadow" registers for those locations that you can also connect to SignalTap. A shadow register is write-only latch that gets updated whenever the corresponding address on the memory address bus gets written to.

Comment: I was expecting a spreadsheet like interface in which we have list of addresses on left and value in them on the right. Will consider signaltap as well.

Comment: If you're just looking for the ability to see the values of a list of variables when stopped at a breakpoint, doesn't the Monitor window in the Nios II GNU debugger console meet that need? See [this document](https://www.altera.com/literature/hb/nios2/edh_ed51003.pdf) for an overview of software debugging on the Nios II.

Comment: ahaaaa the monitor window, that is a good idea. I am trying to learn the Eclipse IDE. I have not done anything complex in it before. Just trying to get my head around it at this time. Thanks for the input.